# Using hadoop in eclipse without an InputFile

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I want to use Hadoop mapreduce in eclipse without an input file , basically I have a list of objects and I want to use that list to create everything I need (Key and Value) How can I do that? I have made some research but all the InputFormat seems to work with a Input File

For the moment I have this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext; 


public class SolverInputFormatClass extends RecordReader<Text,PropNogood>{

private Integer key=null;

private PropNogood value=null;

private List<PropNogood> list=null;

private int p=0;

@Override

public void close() throws IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(!list.iterator().hasNext()){

        list=null;
        }

        key=null;

        value=null;
    }


@Override

public Text getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new Text(this.key+value.varstoString());
    }


@Override

public PropNogood getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return this.value;
    }


@Override

public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return this.list.indexOf(value)/this.list.size();
    }


@Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


@Override

public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(p<list.size()){

            value=list.get(p);

            key=value.cardinality();

            p++;

            return true;

        }

        else{

            return false;

        }


}

}
```

But I'm not sure how to initialize the list.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You should provide some code to help users understanding your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! @AntoineThiry I have posted the code I have